# How can I delete the Summary section of my LinkedIn profile?

Tags: linkedin

I find my *Summary* section of my profile to be a bit bland, and I would like to delete it altogether until I write up something nicer.

Most other sections will automatically delete themselves when there is no content in them, but this doesn't work for the *Summary* section.

Is there any way to delete the *Summary* section altogether? Why would LinkedIn require you to have this section and not others?

Answer (score 8):

If you just delete all the text from the summary section and hit save it will go away

Comment: This is the correct answer.  The method above did not work for either myself or my wife.

Comment: Sadly it still shows up in the PDF export with horizontal rules above & below the section and "N/A" shown where the summary text would be. Why?!

Answer (score 5):

I did not found any option to delete the summary. Anyhow, you can hide the summary section from getting displayed to the public through configuration.

**Step 1**

Just navigate to the Edit Profile option in the dashboard of your LinkedIn and Click it.

When the page is shown, hover over to the down arrow next to the Edit Profile button.

[image: Manage public profile settings]

**Step 2**

Now when you navigate to the manage public profile settings and click.

The options cited on the right hand side of the resulting page will help to changes the settings.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I unchecked that box and saved the profile but the summary still shows.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of your profile are you looking at? I noticed that the dashboard only provides options as to what shows on your "public" profile, which I see is different than what shows to your connections and what you see on your own page.  When you are on your page, click on the blue button that says "View profile as" below the menu bar saying "Home  Profile  My Network" there is a grey bar that says "This is what your profile looks like to Connections" If you click on "Connections" you can see what others see on your profile. Again, I've only seen where you can change what the public sees on your page rather than what connections see.

Answer (score -1):

Navigate to your profile and click on the draw Icon that's next to your profile picture on the right corner. Scroll down to the bottom when the pop window opens and you'll find the section to update your summary.